# VBA Loop to increment dates by 14 days in specified cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a loop to increment the date (Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute) by 14 days in specified cells.

Cell A2 is the start date, Cell A3 is the incremented date by 14, and Cell B3 is the stop date.

| Sheet |  |
| --- | --- |
| 3/1/2020 0:00 |  |
| 3/14/2020 11:59 | 12/31/2020 11:59 |

I have used the following code to increment Cells A2 and A3 by 1 day, but I can't figure out how to increment the days by 14.

The final date the loop would stop at is the date set in cell B3.

Also, when the code seems to start the date at 1/1/1900 instead of the date specified in cell A2 for some reason. Is there a way I can start the loop at the specified date in cell A2?

```
Sub test()
  Start = Val(Range("A1").Value)
  For Row = Val(Range("A3").Value) To Val(Range("B3").Value)
    Range("A" & Row).Value = Start + Row
  Next

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dateadd` to do this.

```
    Dim mydate As Date
    Dim row As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        mydate = DateAdd("d", 14, .Cells(2, 1).Value) 'Get first increment
        row = 3 'First row to place values in
        
        Do Until mydate >= .Cells(3, 2).Value
            .Cells(row, 1).Value = mydate
            row = row + 1
            mydate = DateAdd("d", 14, mydate)
        Loop
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Warcupine, is there a way to update cells A2 and A3 with the new incremented values instead of listing the the values in new rows?

Comment: Change `Row = 3` to `Row = 2` there are 20 new dates though, not sure where you want the rest

Comment: The dates would continue to update in the same cells - for example 3/1/2020 in cell A2 and 3/14/2020 in cell A3 will get updated to 3/15/2020 in cell A2 and 3/29/2020 in cell A3. This script is for updating dates to pull data from a server. Sorry, I should have been more clear :)

Comment: It looks like                                                                                        
```Range("A2").Value = DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(Range("A3"))) /n Range("A3").Value = DateAdd("d", 14, CDate(Range("A3")))``` gets the values in the cell that I need, but how would I implement it into a loop to run until it hits the value set in B3?

Comment: So starting at the value in A1 you want to loop until you arrive at the last value before the value in B3, place that value and the one before it in A2 and A3?

Comment: We would start at A2 with any date that is entered into the cell and arrive at the last value in B3. Then the dates would update in cells A2 and A3 only. Entering code ```Range("A2").Value = DateAdd("d", 0, CDate(Range("A3"))) /n Range("A3").Value = DateAdd("d", 14, CDate(Range("A3")))``` is exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to make a loop for it to stop at the value set in cell B3. Thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub testIncrement14Days()
Dim start As Date, row As Long
 start = Range("A1").value: row = 3

  Do While start <= CDate(Range("C3").value) + 14
    Range("A" & row).value = start + 14
    start = CDate(Range("A" & row).value)
    row = row + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```